# Windows XP not remembering passwords

Tags: windows, passwords

One of my friend is facing an issue with his XP machine. For the past few days none of his IMs rember his password and username.

His system is free of virus.

Any ideas?

Comment: What applications are affected?

Comment: Gogole Talm, MSN and Yahoo messengers

Comment: Isn't this an option that you set in each IM program and not something Windows bothers with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Stefan mentioned, this is most likely a problem with each individual messaging application. Try installing a multi-protocol client like [Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/) and see if you have success with that - otherwise, take a look at the password storing options on each other app.